# Origin of -est verb ending

Tags: etymology, verbs, conjugation

In PIE the corresponding second person verb ending was "-si" and it remains similar in Slavic and Romance. Wiki also states Proto-Germanic ending as "-si", but in German it is "-st", and so it is in English (dost, bringst), even in the verb "to be" there is 't': "art", "bist". Is there a reason for it?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [Linguistics SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), since it deals with Germanic as a whole rather than English in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -st ending in the second person developed in Old English from the use of the second person pronoun (in Old English,**Þu**) as an enclitic.

See p. 110 in *The Origins and Development of the English Language* 7th ed. John Algeo, Carmen Butcher.

Comment: This theory does not explain why you have the same ending in German.

Comment: @fdb: Also [Frisian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Frisian_grammar)... unless these are all parallel developments, it does seem to be older than Old English. But [Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_verbs) appears to just have *s*.